# Saving data into Objects for Json Retrieval

Tags: javascript, json, object, push, jsplumb

I currently am working on saving some data onto objects which will be generated as a Json input and later retrieved via a `load method`. But while am saving the data, due to a for loop that occurs in-between, I am breaking the `.push` and re-pushing elements within the for loop as shown below. But, while retrieving from the Json output generated from this method, I'm unable to access the data pushed from within the for loop and any object value out of the first push method.

I would like to know if there is a way that I can perform all of the needed, within a single `.push` itself. If not, any suggestions in this regard will be much appreciated.

**Code in Context**

```
//First Push
node.push({
    id:idOfEl,
    class:dropElem,
    position:
    {
        top: position.top,
        left: position.left,
        bottom: position.bottom,
        right: position.right
    },
    name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][1],
    fromStream:
    {
        index:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][2][0],
        name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][2][1]
    },
    filter:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][3],
    intoStream:
    {
        index:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][5][0],
        name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][5][1]
    }
});
for(var ct=0;ct<createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4].length;ct++)
{
   //Second Push
    node.push({
        attributes:
        {
            name:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4][ct][0],
            type:createdSimpleQueryArray[elId][4][ct][1]
        }
    });
}
```

**Note**

Though there are two push statements in the above, the object values for all two pushes correspond to a single element.(Like various fields/columns in a record of one element in a database table)

Comment: lot of push here, phew ! mind boggling question, where you are breaking in loop. another is I am still unable to understand what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @A.T. Yeah, totally. That is why am trying to get rid of the second push. Any suggestion?

Comment: @A.T. The only issue here that breaks the push statement is the for loop through which I need to traverse to obtain a few values